# Could not be loaded Xamarin.Forms Android Project After update Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I get the issue
element is missing.  D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets For Xamarn.Android Project After update Visual Studio
Version From Version 16.1 to 16.10

Comment: Have you tried the repair option in vs installer ?

Comment: Actually No, I am tried do that without rapid i will test it immediately and let you know

Comment: @Cfun Not working

Comment: @MikeDarwish Do you get the same error when you create the new project? Could you provide the whole error message for us?

Comment: No the new project working fine

Comment: Do a repair for your VS or you could try to update the VS.

Comment: I Tried To Repair VS and visual studio up to date. keep in your mind the issue appears after update visual studio

Comment: But due to i could not reproduce this issue, it would be better to report via Help>Send feedback> Report a Problem.